# Swing GUI to add a list of numbers entered by the user

Tags: java, swing

I am feeling fairly stupid for not being able to figure out this seemingly simple code, but as a beginner I am stumped. I have a GUI with a textArea for the user to input numbers, a button which should "listen" for those numbers, and then a textField to display the sum.  I have the numbers displaying in the textField but I'm not sure how  to sum them.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private JTextArea inputArea;
private JTextField resultField;
private JButton calcBtn;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Main inst = new Main();
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public Main() {
    super();
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        {
            inputArea = new JTextArea();
            getContentPane().add(inputArea);
            inputArea.setBounds(5, 12, 214, 233);
        }
        {
            calcBtn = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(calcBtn);
            calcBtn.setText("Obtain the sum");
            calcBtn.setBounds(257, 113, 99, 23);
            calcBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    calcBtnActionPerformed(evt);

                }
            });
        }
        {
            resultField = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(resultField);
            resultField.setBounds(242, 55, 139, 28);
        }
        pack();
        setSize(400, 300);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void calcBtnActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {

        String[] lines = inputArea.getText().split("<br/>");

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

            resultField.setText(lines[i]);
        }
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter numbers only");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? It also seems strange that you should be trying to split on `<br/>`, as if this were HTML -- but it's not. Why not split on white space instead,  `\\s+` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Figure out the format of the numbers in the JTextArea.
2. This will tell you how you must extract the information from the text it holds.
3. One way to consider getting the data is to create a new Scanner object with the JTextArea's text
4. Then call `scanner.nextInt()` in a `while (scanner.hasNextInt())` loop.
5. Or you can split on whitespace: `lines = text.split("\\s+");` and then parse each item in the array to int before adding them.
6. Avoid using null layout and setBounds. It will bite you in the tush in the near future.